# How to apply flip Horizontal transition to subview without effecting to superview

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.2, ios5

I have a `superview` and I've added a `subview` on `superview` and  added a `UIbutton` on the `subview`.My requirement is when I click  on `UIbutton` the `flipHorizontal Transition`, How  will this  be applied to `subview`(Nothing but `UIbutton`) without effecting to `superview`(means `superview` is stable one)?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? The answer below flips the superview like you don't want, right?

Answer (score 0):

```
[UIView transitionFromView:view1 toView:view2 
    duration:0.5 
    options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft   
    completion:^(BOOL finished){
    /* do something on animation completion */
}];
```

Make sure you replace view1 with the name of your button you want to flip, and view2 with the view you want the button to be replaced with. You can just put your Button for both of them so it will flip around with no side effects if you like.